# Program fails to receive second input

Tags: c

It's just a code to receive user inputs in C program, but fails to do so and accepts null space as input. I have tried fgets() as well and the same thing keeps happening. Please advice on how to fix.

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
//#include <string.h>
#define len 16
int main(void) 
{
    /* Enter your code here. Read input from STDIN. Print output to STDOUT */
    int n,i=0,j=0; 
    printf("enter the number of cards:");
    n = getchar();
    //scanf("%d",&n);
 
    int c1[len][n],card[len][n];
    char buf[len];
  
    printf("Enter card number:");
    gets(buf);
    
    system("Pause");
    return (0);
}
```

Comment: The function `gets` is no longer part of the ISO C standard. It has been removed for security reasons and should no longer be used (even if it is still provided by your compiler for backward compatibility). You should use `fgets` instead.

Comment: `getchar()` leaves the newline in the buffer and when followed by `fgets()` (or the obsolete `gets()`) they read an "empty string". BTW you probably will find `char buf[len];` is too short - no room for a newline or a terminator. Don't be tight with string lengths.

Comment: @WeatherVane: In contrast to `gets`, `fgets` will read the newline character into the buffer. The string will not be empty.

Comment: Also ```getchar``` is not doing what you think. It reads one character from STDIN, and returns its ASCII Value as an ```int```.  If the user enters ```1``` for number of cards, `n` becomes ```49```.  If the user enters a two digit number eg ```12```, then n is ```49``` and the ```2``` remains in STDIN waiting to be got.

Comment: The function `getchar` will only read a single character at once. If you for example enter "5\n", then the first function call will return '5' and the second function call will return '\n'. Reading a single character at once seems not to be what you want. You should only use `fgets`. In the code you posted, you call `getchar` followed by `gets`. With the example input mentioned above, `getchar` will read '5'` and then `gets` will read the rest of the line (which is empty).

Comment: thank you! helped clear things up.

Answer (score 1):

*"...code to receive user inputs in c program, but fails to do so and accepts null space as input..."*

The reasons your existing code has problems is covered well in the comments under your post.

Consider a different approach: Define the following:

```
char inBuf[80] = {0};//
int numCards = 0;//Pick variable names that are descriptive (n is not)
int cardNum = 0;
bool isnum;
```

Then use it in conjunction with `printf()` etc.

```
 printf("enter the number of cards:");
 if(fgets(inBuf, sizeof(inBuf), stdin))//will read more than just a single char, eg. "12345"
 {
      int len = strlen(inBuf);
      isnum = true;
      for(int i=0;i<len;i++)
      {
          if(!isdigit(inBuf[i]))
          {
               isnum = false;
               break;
          }              
      }
      if(isnum)
      {
          numCards = atoi(inBuf);
      }
      else
      {
          printf("input is not a number\n"
      }
 }
 printf("Enter card number:");
 if(fgets(inBuf, sizeof(inBuf), stdin))
 {
      ...
```

Repeat variations of these lines as needed to read input from `stdin`, with modifications to accommodate assignment statements based on user input i.e. an integer (this example is covered), a floating point number, a string (eg.  a persons name)

Although there is more that you can do to improve this, it is conceptually viable for your stated purpose...